# "Haro sur quelqu'un" : sens et usage

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, interjections

> Haro sur quelqu'un.

Wiki écrit que haro signifie "cry for help". Quelle est alors le sens de la tournure ci-dessus ? Est-elle courante ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est un mot qui n'est plus employé que dans un contexte littéraire ou soutenu et principalement dans l'expression :

> Crier [haro sur le baudet](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/crier-haro-sur-le-baudet). (où *baudet* peut être remplacé par le destinataire ciblé)

Il ne s'agit pas de demander de l'aide mais de soumettre à la réprobation générale une personne (ou un animal ici).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your answers! So in the context here https://www.revuedesdeuxmondes.fr/haro-sur-le-prof-de-philo-didier-lemaire-un-scandale-francais/ what does it mean?

Comment: The philosophy teacher is publicly inveighted against. According to the article, he says the truth but instead of listening, people blame him for that.

Comment: Il n'est quand-même pas rare de le voir utilisé dans des titres d'articles par exemple...

Comment: @LaurentS Oui, je classifie ces usages dans les contextes soutenus.

Answer (score 3):

"Haro"(harout) est (était?) un terme de chasse utilisé pour exciter les chiens lors d'une chasse à courre.

Par extension, crier haro sur quelqu'un revient à faire appel à la vindicte populaire, en d'autres termes utiliser la foule pour porter le discrédit sur quelqu'un.

Comment: *Haro* est plus utilisé pour condamner la chasse à courre qu'en exciter les chiens. https://www.liberation.fr/france/2017/12/14/haro-contre-la-chasse-a-courre_1616636/

Comment: je pense que c'est une manière de "retourner le fusil sur les chasseurs" que d'utiliser un terme de chasse pour condamner la chasse.

Comment: Je comprends, mais il me semblait que *haro* n'était plus employé depuis longtemps dans ce contexte. Cela dit, je ne suis pas du tout, mais alors pas du tout expert en chasse à courre...

Comment: J'aurais effectivement dû employer l'imparfait au lieu du présent. Je ne suis pas expert en chasse non plus, mais c'est une explication qu'une connaissance m'avait donné.